# HMAC Signature doesn't match x-hub-signature from github

Tags: javascript, node.js, cryptography, webhooks, hmac

I'm handling an incoming Webhook from github, and wants to verify the x-hub-signature. I'm using `hmac`to hash the "secret", and then compares the two hashes. The problem is that they never match. This is my setup:

```
router.route("/auth")

.post((req, res) => {

    var hmac = crypto.createHmac("sha1", process.env.WEBHOOK_SECRET);
    var calculatedSignature = "sha1=" + hmac.update(JSON.stringify(req.body)).digest("hex");
    console.log(req.headers["x-hub-signature"] === calculatedSignature); // Returns false
    console.log(req.headers["x-hub-signature"]) // => sha1=blablabla
    console.log(calculatedSignature) // => sha1=foofoofoo

    res.end();
});
```

I've tried everything, but can't make it work. Wondering if the `hmac.update()` should hold another parameter than `JSON.stringify(req.body)`. Does anyone know why they won't match?

Answer (score 1):

So the problem was with the settings of the webhook. The content-format was set to application/x-www-form-urlencoded, which for some reason hashed the x-hub-signature differently. I just changed it to application/json, and then it worked!

Comment: From where did you change the content-format? I don't find any way to set settings of this webhook.

Comment: This worked for me! Many thanks. @snl You change the content-format on github.com, under the settings for the repository, webhooks.

Answer (score 0):

If the webhook Content-Type is set to `application/x-www-url-encoded` then string you need to use to check the HMAC is
`"payload=" + query_encoded_payload`.

For example in golang

```
payloadForm := r.PostFormValue("payload")
escaped := url.QueryEscape(payloadForm) # ex. http://www.url-encode-decode.com/
checkMe := "payload=" + escaped
```