# Why does my Github secret fail (change on each event)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, github, ecmascript-6, webhooks

I am trying to verify the Github webhook secret, but each time I trigger an event in Github, the value of `req.headers['x-hub-signature'])` changes, which doesn't make sense.

```
NodeJs: sha1=b57ad18e45f71ac069d15618f6ca547ed75bb2e9
Github: sha1=0b6ff08d557b240dbadedb2a0c1054ce69f2d93e    <----

NodeJs: sha1=b57ad18e45f71ac069d15618f6ca547ed75bb2e9
Github: sha1=15e3d5edae00951abb180e9eaea9a6278d8f8d0b    <----
```

Notice the secret that comes from Githit hub is different each time!

I have found others that verify the secret, but I don't see how their code is different from mine.

- https://humanwhocodes.com/snippets/2020/08/validate-github-webhook-signature-nodejs/
- https://gist.github.com/kiewic/a419b8e47b3baf9a301dee598d6ade87
- [HMAC Signature doesn't match x-hub-signature from github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42788246/hmac-signature-doesnt-match-x-hub-signature-from-github)
- https://gist.github.com/stigok/57d075c1cf2a609cb758898c0b202428

## Question

Can anyone figure out why I get different secrets from Github on each event? Or am I doing something wrong?

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const crypto = require('crypto');
const secret = "x";

const app = express();
const PORT = 8080;

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post("/", (req, res) => {

let sig = "sha1=" + crypto.createHmac('sha1', secret).digest('hex');

  console.log('NodeJs: ' + sig);
  console.log('Github: ' + req.headers['x-hub-signature']);
    
  res.status(200).end();
});

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Github wekhook listening on port ${PORT}`));
```

Comment: The code you've linked to *is* different, they're getting the value to compare with from the environment (`WEBHOOK_SECRET`, for GitHub), not hard-coding it. This also makes their code safer to share, you should generally **not** put tokens in version control.

Comment: @jonrsharpe My code is just a PoC, so I can understand what is going on. Can you modify my code to use `WEBHOOK_SECRET`? I don't understand the difference.

Comment: Look at that first example you posted, it shows exactly how to access and use the env var.

Comment: So you are talking about secure parsing of the secret? Yes, that is a good idea, but the OP is about why I get a different secret from Github in each event.

Comment: GitHub actively detects tokens included in source code, and revokes them. See the Security tab in the web UI.

Answer (score 0):

`req.headers['x-hub-signature'])` is not a hash of the secret, but `req.body` signed with the secret. That is why it is different on each event.

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const crypto = require('crypto');
const secret = "x";

const app = express();
const PORT = 8080;

app.use(bodyParser.json());

function isSigOk(request, secret) {
    // calculate the signature
    const expectedSignature = "sha1=" +
        crypto.createHmac("sha1", secret)
            .update(JSON.stringify(request.body))
            .digest("hex");

    // compare the signature against the one in the request
    const signature = request.headers["x-hub-signature"];
    if (signature !== expectedSignature) {
        throw new Error("Invalid signature.");
    };
};

app.post("/", (req, res) => {
  // will throw an error if not ok
  isSigOk(req, secret);

  // Do stuff here

  res.status(200).end();
});

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Github wekhook listening on port ${PORT}`));
```